# jQuery noconflict, bootstrap and requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

The environment I'm developing in is using jQuery 1.7.1 while I need to use specifically jQuery 2.1.3. But when I do use 2.1.3 some legacy code breaks (as its using 1.7.1) so I had to use jQuery.noconflict on 2.1.3

jquery-private.js:

```
define(["jquery"], function(jQuery){
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

so then inside my requirejs config file I have this:

config.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'js/jquery/jquery',
        'jqueryui': 'js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
        'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap',
    },
    map: {
        // '*' means all modules will get 'jquery-private'
        // for their 'jquery' dependency.
        '*': {
            'jquery': 'jquery-private'
        },

        // 'jquery-private' wants the real jQuery module
        // though. If this line was not here, there would
        // be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.
        'jquery-private': {
            'jquery': 'jquery'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

so then when I require bootstrap

widget.js:

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "bootstrap"
], function(jqr){
    // SOME CODE
});
```

I get an error:

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

So bootstrap is picking up 1.7.1.

How can I make it pickup 2.1.3 without making changes to bootstrap.js file?

Comment: not sure but jQuery does provide a jQuery Migrate plugin to provide support to deprecated API's. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: 1.7.1 supports IE6/7 so I need to keep it there as some legacy code requires it

Comment: i have never worked with require js but can we add 'jqueryLatest': 'js/jquery/latest/jquery', to the paths and pass it as dependencies where latest version of jQuery required? Just a thought

Comment: @Lokesh Yadav bootstrap extends jQuery so this will not work as it will introduce jQuery 2.1.3 back which I was trying to "hide" by using noconflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why it is failing?

Your current attempt cannot work because your `jquery-private` setup ensures that as soon as jQuery is loaded as a RequireJS module, `noConflict()` is called. So long as the code loaded with RequireJS is referring to jQuery through a `define` call (e.g. `define(['jquery'], function ($) {`) there is no problem. However, any code that is shimmed will refer to the `$` or `jQuery` globals and thus will refer version 1.7.1.

#### A Solution

*Absent any other constraints*, the preferred solution is to have the entire code base use the same jQuery version. Upgrade 1.7.1 to the latest in the 1.x series, and use that. According to the [download page](https://jquery.com/download/), there is no API difference between 2.x and a relatively recent release in the 1.x series (I would say 1.9.x and later). Of course, this means that the code that depended on 1.7.1 may have to be updated to work with the latest jQuery in the 1.x series.

I would have suggested upgrading to the 2.x series but you mention in comments needing compatibility with IE 6 and 7. Note here: if you do manage to get 1.7.1 and 2.1.3 to load for the same page, that part of the code that uses 2.1.3 wont' be compatible with IE 6 and 7 so the page is effectively no longer compatible with IE 6 and 7.

To use this solution, besides the changes that must be done for the upgrade, you must:

1. Make sure that jQuery loads *before* RequireJS. Otherwise, it will detect RequireJS and call `define` but then it won't be *reliably* available to code that is not loaded with RequireJS. (I said it won't be "reliably available" because although once the `jquery` module is loaded, then the `jQuery` and `$` globals will exist, the problem is that code that is not loaded with RequireJS cannot *wait* for RequireJS to load jQuery. So, unless you take pains to write your own synchronization code, it won't work reliably.)
2. Create a RequireJS module which merely makes the jQuery loaded before RequireJS available to RequireJS modules as a module, so:

   ```
    define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
   ```

This could be placed just before your call to `require.config`. This creates a "fake" `jquery` module which merely returns the global `jQuery` symbol. (It could just as well return `$`.)

#### Alternatives?

I do not see a *robust* alternative to the solution above. It is not that difficult to come up with a proof of concept that would demonstrate another approach. However, it would fail as soon as you try to use it on a real project. The problem is that RequireJS is inherently asynchronous, so you cannot start messing with the `$` and `jQuery` globals to set them the way you want and be sure that everything you want to happen will happen *at the time you want it to happen*. Moreover, any code loaded before RequireJS that happens to initiate asynchronous operations that could happen interleaved with RequireJS' module loading would throw a monkey wrench into the whole operation. I'd rather refrain from proposing solutions that will fail as soon as they go from proof of concept to real world applications.

I have better solution to define this module as this

```js
    define(function(require) {
        var $ = require('jquery');
        //drop the `true` if you want jQuery (but not $) to remain global
        return $.noConflict(true);
    });
```

Comment: I've created a jquery module like in your suggestion #2. Now its always returning the exactly same version I need. Thank you again!